# Cannot GET / Error serving client files on deploying a mern stack app to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, mern

I deployed a mern stack app to heroku and deployment was sucessful, the app works fine on local development server, but when I click on the deployed app link https://immense-sands-74220.herokuapp.com
I get a Cannot Get / error, and after hours of searching i am pretty sure that there is a problem with my server code serving the client views when the app runs, I tried using the code below:

```js
const path = require('path');
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')))

 app.get('*', function(_, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, resolvedPath), function(err) {
     if (err) {
       res.status(500).send(err)
     }
   })
 })
```

but i ended up with this error: [image]

server.js

```js
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
// const path = require('path');
// const filePath = "./client/public/index.html"
// const resolvedPath = path.resolve(filePath);

// console.log(resolvedPath);



const notesRouter = require("./routes/notes");
const registerRouter =  require("./routes/signup");
const loginRouter = require("./routes/signin");

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors()); 

app.use(express.json());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use( bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     
  extended: true
}));   

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(session({
  secret:"This is keeper clone.",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://Karim:keeper@keeper.ickkk.mongodb.net/keeperDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", () => {
    console.log("MongoDb database connection established successfully");
});

const User = require("./models/users");
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(express.static('/public/index.html'));



app.use("/", notesRouter);
app.use("/", registerRouter);
app.use("/", loginRouter);


// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')))

// app.get('*', function(_, res) {
//   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, resolvedPath), function(err) {
//     if (err) {
//       res.status(500).send(err)
//     }
//   })
// })

  


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000!");
});
```

client package.json

```js
{
  "name": "keeper",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heruko-postbuild": "npm install && npm run-script build && npm run-script start:prod0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.13",
    "mongoose-findorcreate": "^3.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

server package.json

```js
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.10",
    "mongoose-findorcreate": "^3.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^6.1.0"
  }
}
```

This is my project directory structure

[image]

client package.json file may contain some node.js dependencies and this is because I had my directory structure switched so that backend was in a seperate folder and client files were in the root directory and I kept getting errors of module_not_found on each node dependency on deploying to heroku,
Any help would be very appreciated as I've spent more than 6 hours now fixing issues related to heroku deployment trying to clear heroku logs issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it works for me on heroku

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === “production”) {
   app.use(express.static(“client/build”));
   app.get(“*”, (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, “client”, “build”, “index.html”));
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where your problem is, but make sure you remember to configure any environment variables in your Heroku project settings.  Also, I have an app that is currently deployed on Heroku (free tier, no addons, no upgrades) and working that uses almost the same stack with a similar project structure.  You might be able to reference it and fix your problem.  The code is here: https://github.com/Perrottarichard/pizzapizza-server